# How to use sf::st_join and avoid filling in values if polygon mostly covers empty space?

Tags: r, spatial-join, sf

I am using `sf::st_join` in R to join two polygon layers. One of the two layers (`sample`) was created from a rasterised subset of the other (`patches`).
I would like to extract the values from the subset into the original polygon layer where the polygons are "identical". (Of course, rasterising causes touching polygons to be merged and in such cases, the new, larger patch will provide the value of all contained original patches.)

When I run

```
sf::st_join(patches, sample, join = st_intersects, largest = TRUE)
```

polygons in `patches` adjacent to polygons in `sample` are assigned values, despite they merely touch and should, thus, be assigned `NA`.
I also tried `st_covered_by`, `st_covers` and `st_overlaps` with no success. Is there a solution to the problem?

**Edit**

Here is a small extent of the area. Pink polygons are those polygons in `patches` which do not contain any value from `sample` after a spatial join using "intersect". Those which do contain values are coloured green, and the vector layer `sample` is orange.

[image: example image showing the polygon layers]

So, I think the question is: During spatial join, how can I check whether a polygon overlaps mostly with empty space and then assign NoData instead of the value of the largest overlapping polygon?

---

Maybe it should be noted I had to run

```
sf::st_crs(sample) <- sf::st_crs(patches)
```

since the program exporting `sample` used

```
Coordinate Reference System:
  User input: CH1903+ / LV95 
  wkt:
BOUNDCRS[
    SOURCECRS[
        PROJCRS["CH1903+ / LV95",
            BASEGEOGCRS["CH1903+",
                DATUM["CH1903+",
                    ELLIPSOID["Bessel 1841",6377397.155,299.1528128,
                        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
                PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]]],
            CONVERSION["unnamed",
                METHOD["Oblique_Mercator"],
                PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",7.43958333333333,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",46.9524055555556,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                PARAMETER["azimuth",90,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                PARAMETER["scale_factor",1,
                    SCALEUNIT["unity",1]],
                PARAMETER["false_easting",2600000,
                    LENGTHUNIT["m",1]],
                PARAMETER["false_northing",1200000,
                    LENGTHUNIT["m",1]],
                PARAMETER["rectified_grid_angle",90,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]]],
            CS[Cartesian,2],
                AXIS["easting",east,
                    ORDER[1],
                    LENGTHUNIT["m",1]],
                AXIS["northing",north,
                    ORDER[2],
                    LENGTHUNIT["m",1]],
            ID["EPSG",2056]]],
    TARGETCRS[
        GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
            DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
                ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                AXIS["latitude",north,
                    ORDER[1],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                AXIS["longitude",east,
                    ORDER[2],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            ID["EPSG",4326]]],
    ABRIDGEDTRANSFORMATION["Transformation from CH1903+ to WGS84",
        METHOD["Position Vector transformation (geog2D domain)",
            ID["EPSG",9606]],
        PARAMETER["X-axis translation",674.374,
            ID["EPSG",8605]],
        PARAMETER["Y-axis translation",15.056,
            ID["EPSG",8606]],
        PARAMETER["Z-axis translation",405.346,
            ID["EPSG",8607]],
        PARAMETER["X-axis rotation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8608]],
        PARAMETER["Y-axis rotation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8609]],
        PARAMETER["Z-axis rotation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8610]],
        PARAMETER["Scale difference",1,
            ID["EPSG",8611]]]]
```

which is not identical to the one used by `patches`:

```
Coordinate Reference System:
  User input: CH1903+ / LV95 
  wkt:
PROJCRS["CH1903+ / LV95",
    BASEGEOGCRS["CH1903+",
        DATUM["CH1903+",
            ELLIPSOID["Bessel 1841",6377397.155,299.1528128,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4150]],
    CONVERSION["Swiss Oblique Mercator 1995",
        METHOD["Hotine Oblique Mercator (variant B)",
            ID["EPSG",9815]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of projection centre",46.9524055555556,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8811]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of projection centre",7.43958333333333,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8812]],
        PARAMETER["Azimuth of initial line",90,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8813]],
        PARAMETER["Angle from Rectified to Skew Grid",90,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8814]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor on initial line",1,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8815]],
        PARAMETER["Easting at projection centre",2600000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8816]],
        PARAMETER["Northing at projection centre",1200000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8817]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Cadastre, engineering survey, topographic mapping (large and medium scale)."],
        AREA["Liechtenstein; Switzerland."],
        BBOX[45.82,5.96,47.81,10.49]],
    ID["EPSG",2056]]
```

**Edit#2**

This is one solution (however, undesirable, since it is very slow and cumbersome):

```
# Create a polygon from the boundary box
bbox_coords <- sf::st_bbox(sample)
background_area <- sf::st_sfc(
  sf::st_polygon(
    list(
      cbind(
        bbox_coords[c(1, 3, 3, 1, 1)],
        bbox_coords[c(2, 2, 4, 4, 2)]
      )
    )
  ),
  crs = sf::st_crs(patches_shp)
)

background_area <- sf::st_as_sf(background_area)

background <- sf::st_as_sf(
  sf::st_difference(
    sf::st_geometry(background_area),
    sf::st_union(sf::st_geometry(sample))
  )
) %>%
  sf::st_cast("POLYGON")

# Format the background polygon to resemble sample
bg <- cbind(
  background,
  matrix(
    rep(NA, (ncol(sample) - 1) * nrow(background)),
    nrow = nrow(background)
  )
)

sf::st_geometry(bg) <- "geometry"
names(bg)[1:(ncol(bg) - 1)] <- names(sample)[1:(ncol(bg) - 1)]

sample <- rbind(sample, bg)

# Spatial join
sf::st_join(
  patches,
  sample,
  join = st_intersects,
  largest = TRUE,
  left = TRUE
)
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what's going on here. Could you make a diagram, showing us more about how the parts of the data relate to each other? Are `patches` and `sample` both vector data, despite `sample` being somehow derived from a rasterized `patches`, and then vectorised again?

Comment: @Spacedman Yes, they are both vector data. A random subset of ```patches``` was rasterised (binary, simply patch and no patch. the raster is entirely without information on polygon ID). The resulting raster was subsequently vectorised, and polygons were assigned values by the Graphab Java program. Now, I want to join these values into the original raster.